# Restrict function parameters to certain enum values

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, c++17

Here's my first attempt -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum class props {
    left, right
};

template<typename T>
auto allowLeftOnly(T p) -> decltype((p==props::left), void())
{
    cout << "Wow!";
}

int main() {
    props p1 = props::left;
    props p2 = props::right;
    allowLeftOnly(p1);
    // allowLeftOnly(p2);  // should fail to compile
}
```

What I want from `allowLeftOnly` function is to accept only `props::left` or others that I explicitly specify as parameters and fail to compile for others. Is that possible?

Comment: You would have to make `p` a template parameter to do what you want to do.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve with this solution? *Why* do you want to do this? Please take some time to read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and reflect on how your question is an example of it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude not trying to solve anything substantial, trying to learn TMP side of c++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Values of `p1` and `p2` are run-time properties, not compile time properties, hence the compiler does not "know" their values at compile-time.

You can make them known at compile-time by using `constexpr`, and pass them as template arguments instead, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class props {
    left, right
};

template <props v>
typename std::enable_if<v == props::left, void>::type allowLeftOnly()
{ std::cout << "Wow!\n"; }

int main() {
    constexpr auto p1 = props::left;
    constexpr auto p2 = props::right;
    allowLeftOnly<p1>();
    allowLeftOnly<p2>(); // Fails to compile
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change `p` in to a template parameter and then use `std::enable_if`, like this:

```
template <props p> // p is now a template parameter
std::enable_if_t<p == props::left> // We only allow p == props::left, return type is implicitly void
allowLeftOnly() // No 'normal' parameters anymore
{
    std::cout << "Wow!";
}

int main()
{
    constexpr props p1 = props::left;
    constexpr props p2 = props::right;
    allowLeftOnly<p1>();
    // allowLeftOnly<p2>();  // Fails to compile
}
```

For `p1` and `p2` the `constexpr` keyword ensures we can use the variables as template parameters.

If you later want another return type, e.g., `int` then use:

```
std::enable_if_t<p == props::left, int>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers suggest to use a template parameter, I'll also add an answer that show how this can be implemented using tag-dispatching ([description from boost.org](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching)):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct props
{
    struct left {};
    struct right {};
};

void allowLeftOnly(props::left p)
{
    cout << "Wow!";
}

int main()
{
    allowLeftOnly(props::left{});
    // allowLeftOnly(props::right{});  // Fails to compile
}
```